# JavaScript - using named constructors

Tags: javascript

I have been using dart OOP a lot lately and there we used to have named constructors like `DateTime.now().`

How do we use the same functionality in JavaScript, with a default constructor and other named constructors for the class ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this like this:

```
class MultiConstructor {
   constructor() {
      // default constructor
   }

   //...other methods
}

MultiConstructor.now = function() {
  const res = new MultiConstructor()
  // configure object
  return res
}
```